# Hover over button display's hidden textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to create a simple search bar where once you hover over a simple button it will display a textbox on the left. How would i be able to go about this with CSS and javascript. After using David Fregoli response,

```
$('#idofthebutton').hover(function () {
$('#idoftextbox').show();
}, function () {
$('#idoftextbox').hide();
});
```

How would i be able to have it fixed either once I click on the search, or allow me to hover over the text box as well due to the hover over function is only over the button. So the text box will disappear when attempting to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#idofthebutton').hover(function () {
    $('#idoftextbox').show();
}, function () {
    $('#idoftextbox').hide();
});
```

Comment: This is more or less exactly what im looking for but is there a way so once you click on the button it will select the search box, as it usually disappears once you try to click onto it. Or another function so after you hover over it the whole section will be visible

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBJOYY)

It simply sets `display: block` for `#two` when the `:hover` state of `#one` is triggered